# Is there a sequenced-before relationship between the evaluation of the lhs of the member access operator and the side-effects of its arguments?

Tags: c++, expression, c++14, side-effects

I have read [Order of evalution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) from cppreference, but I couldn't find any rule which concerns this situation. Is this means that there is no sequenced-before relationship or did I miss something? Thanks.

The following code snippet gives an exemple.

```
#include <memory>

struct Foo {
  void func(std::unique_ptr<Foo>) {}
};

int main() {
  auto ptr = std::make_unique<Foo>();
  ptr->func(std::move(ptr)); // Is this valid?
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prior C++1z **NO**, don't write that.

Post C++1z yes, from [[expr.call]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#expr.call-5)

> The postfix-expression is sequenced before each expression in the expression-list and any default argument.

Postfix expression here is the function call, hence the order of execution would be similar to

```
auto ptr_ = ptr.operator->();
auto func_ = &decltype(ptr)::element_type::func;
ptr_->*func_(std::move(ptr));
```

Which is of course correct.

Comment: Technically you're quoting [expr.call], describing function call expressions only.  But this specific postfix-expression happens to be `ptr->func`, so it is indeed sequenced before the only expression in the expression-list

Comment: @Cubbi Oops, yeah that was a mistake. Although I do remember seeing the original proposal saying something like that.